# MulterError: Unexpected field in Express.js with multer

Tags: express, next.js, multer, react-hook-form, shadcnui

I'm currently working on an Express.js application where I'm trying to handle file uploads using Multer. However, I'm encountering an issue with the error message "MulterError: Unexpected field" when I attempt to upload files.

Interestingly, when I tested file uploads using Postman, I successfully received image data without encountering any errors.

Here's the code snippet from my Express route:

```
const route = express.Router()
const upload = multer()

route.post('/add-product', upload.array('image', 4), async (req, res) => {
  const imageFiles = req.files
  console.log(' ~ imageFiles:', imageFiles)
  const productData = req.body
  console.log(' ~ productData:', productData)
  const imageUrls = []
  // Handle the files and product data as needed
})
```

handler

```
    const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
    const handleUpload = (file: File) => {
        setUploadedImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, file]);
    };

  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof productValidation>) {
        try {
            values.category = await extractIdsFromArray(values?.category);
            const response = await addProduct({
                ...values, 
                image: uploadedImages,
            }).unwrap();

            console.log(" ~ onSubmit ~ response:", response);

            if (response?.success) {
                toast.success(response?.message);
                // refetch();
            } else {
                toast.error(response?.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(" ~ onSubmit ~ error:", error);
            // @ts-ignore
            toast.error("An unexpected error occurred!", error?.data?.message);
        }
    }
```

some sinipade of image upload code

```
 <FormField
                                        control={form.control}
                                        name="image"
                                        render={({ field }) => (
                                            <FormItem>
                                                <FormLabel>
                                                    Product Images
                                                </FormLabel>
                                                <FormControl>
                                                    <MultipleImageUpload
                                                        onUpload={handleUpload}
                                                        setUploadedImages={
                                                            setUploadedImages
                                                        }
                                                    />
                                                </FormControl>
                                                <FormMessage />
                                                <FormMessage />
                                            </FormItem>
                                        )}
                                    />
```

multiple image uploader

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { AlertCircle, ImageIcon, ImageMinus, XIcon } from "lucide-react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import * as z from "zod";
import { Alert, AlertDescription, AlertTitle } from "./alert";
import { toast } from "sonner";

const MultipleImageUpload = ({
    onUpload,
    setUploadedImages,
}: {
    onUpload: any;
    setUploadedImages: any;
}) => {
    const [previewUrls, setPreviewUrls] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const imageValidation = z.string().refine(
        (value) => {
            const extension = value.split(".").pop()?.toLowerCase();
            return (
                extension === "jpg" ||
                extension === "jpeg" ||
                extension === "png"
            );
        },
        {
            message: "Invalid image format. Only JPG, JPEG, or PNG allowed.",
        }
    );

    const maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB in bytes
    const maxImages = 4;

    const onDrop = useCallback(
        (acceptedFiles: any) => {
            const newPreviewUrls: string[] = [];

            acceptedFiles.slice(0, maxImages).forEach((file: File) => {
                const validationResult = imageValidation.safeParse(file.name);
                if (!validationResult.success) {
                    const errorMessage =
                        validationResult.error.errors[0].message;

                    toast.error(errorMessage);
                    return;
                }

                if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
                    toast.error(
                        "Image size exceeds 5 MB. Please choose a smaller image."
                    );

                    return;
                }

                const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                newPreviewUrls.push(fileUrl);
                onUpload(file);
            });

            setPreviewUrls((prev) => [...prev, ...newPreviewUrls]);
        },
        [onUpload, imageValidation]
    );

    const handleRemove = (index: number) => {
        // Remove the removed image from uploadedImages state
        setUploadedImages((prevImages: File[]) => {
            const updatedImages = [...prevImages];
            updatedImages.splice(index, 1);
            return updatedImages;
        });

        const updatedPreviewUrls = [...previewUrls];
        updatedPreviewUrls.splice(index, 1);
        setPreviewUrls(updatedPreviewUrls);
    };

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
        onDrop,
    });

    return (
        <div
            {...getRootProps()}
            className="border border-dashed border-input p-4 rounded-md"
        >
            <input accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" {...getInputProps()} />
            {isDragActive ? (
                <p>Drop the images here...</p>
            ) : (
                <p>Drag 'n' drop images here, or click to select images</p>
            )}
            <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-4">
                {previewUrls.map((url, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="relative">
                        <button
                            onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}
                            className="absolute top-2 right-2 bg-white rounded-full p-1 z-50"
                        >
                            <XIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-red-500" />
                        </button>
                        <Image
                            key={url}
                            src={url}
                            alt="Image"
                            className="rounded-md object-cover w-full h-full"
                            width={200}
                            height={200}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MultipleImageUpload;
```

redux end point

```
 addProduct: build.mutation({
            query: (product) => ({
                url: "/product/add-product/",
                method: "POST",
                data: product,
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ["product"],
        }),
```

error images:

[image]

I've ensured that the field name 'image' matches between the front-end form and the Multer configuration. I'm also using the correct enctype attribute in my form (multipart/form-data).

Despite these checks, I'm still encountering the "MulterError: Unexpected field" error. Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've double-checked the field names, verified the form's encoding type, and reviewed the Multer documentation, but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the error.